How to display "bookmark this page" message?
I create for a user a page with codes like yszsi-oeaaa-aaaaa-qac7a-cai in the name (these are principals of IC network). So, the user cannot remember the full URL and would lose it without bookmarking.
I want to display message "Please, bookmark this page." to the user, but how to determine when this message is to be displayed and when not?
Should I display it at the first page load? Should I display it with a closing cross and show on each page load, till the user clicks the cross?
Anything better than two strategies of the previous paragraph?
Currently it is erroneously implemented as: Display the message, if bookmarkMsg=1 in GET params. It is an error, because the user would bookmark the full URL including bookmarkMsg=1, so that the message would be displayed persistently.

Why is it important for the user to bookmark the page?

@Ren The URL contains keys like be2us-64aaa-aaaaa-qaabq-cai, that a user cannot remember. If the URL won't be stored, the user loses the app installation, for which he paid some money.

Why not just send an email with the installation link?

@Ren The user may read and delete the email, so losing the link without any ability to recover it.

Deletion at user discretion holds true for both bookmark as well as email. There are too many risks in the bookmark way. What if there is a network error on the user's side and the system is disconnected long enough to dismiss the process?

@Ren If there is a network error on the user's side and the system is disconnected long enough to dismiss the process, then the user needs to start the process anew after losing a small amount of money.
